# Исчезновение элементов

Tags: java, android

Доброе время суток. Я хотел добавить элемент Scroll View, но при добавлении его, кнопки меняют место расположение. Можно ли как-то поченить это с оставлением Scroll View.
Вот сам файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="1">

            <!-- everything you already have -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/idImageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/yads1_1"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/idImageView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="265dp"
                android:src="@drawable/yads1_2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="DuplicateIds,MissingConstraints" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/idButton"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="115dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="215dp"
                android:onClick="buttonClick"
                android:text="Скачати"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints,OnClick" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/idButton1"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="115dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
                android:onClick="buttonClick"
                android:text="Скачати"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="DuplicateIds,HardcodedText,MissingConstraints,OnClick" />
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В ConstraintLayout все элементы д.б. привязаны к чему либо. Если нет, то они при запуске будут скидываться на начальную точку в 0.